# Curl, matching a string in website response content

Tags: apache-2.2, curl

Is there any way that i can verify the contents of a page, if they exist in it? like if i open google.com, if its page content has "Error" in it, then i can know that the page is not opened correctly. (i already know the ways to check the page status codes check, like 200, 400 ,404 or 500 etc), i am actually interested in getting and comparing the content of a page against a string and take required action based on that string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure how you can dump formatted web file using curl. If you simply use curl to download the site, and do a string search in it, you might end up getting the wrong result. All the html tags, javascript codes... will be searched.

You might try using `lynx` , textual command line browser, with the `-dump` option set to format the output and then do `grep` to find a string match.

```
root@localhost:/t# lynx -dump www.google.com | grep -i "Feeling Lucky"
Google Search  I'm Feeling Lucky                          [12]Advanced search
```

Comment: Thanks :) 
Sometimes the solution is just near us, but we think somewhere else, far beyond for it..